# When does $A(x^2+y^2+z^2)=B(xy + yz + xz)$ have nontrivial integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Someone on MathematicaSE asked for which coprime integer pairs $(A,B)$ satisfying $A<B$ the equation $A(x^2+y^2+z^2)=B(xy + yz + xz)$ admits nontrivial integer solutions. The question was closed there, but I figured it would be a nice courtesy to re-ask it here instead.

There are really three questions:

- Are all such $(A,B)$ pairs known?
- If not, is there any reference containing an exhaustive list of all pairs satisfying $0<A<B<N$ for some moderately large integer $N$ (say $N=1000$)?
- If not, does there exist a software library or algorithms which provide an efficient search method that avoids brute-force enumeration?

Comment: Just come considerations. If $|B|<|A|$ there are no solutions by the AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Probably there are some additional arithmetical constraints $\pmod{4}$ or $\pmod{8}$, but provided that such equation has a non-trivial solution, it has an infinite number of them by Vieta jumping.

Comment: Your two questions look supernumerary

Comment: @belisarius: It's a "New Kind of Two".

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks, I had seen that thread before, but didn't read it too closely. Seeing as you've provided a couple criteria that rule out certain $(A,B)$, I'll try to combine them and make a program that calculates the $(A,B)$ pairs efficiently.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus, there is a method, in Cassels *Rational Quadratic Forms* using the Hilbert Norm Residue symbol for each prime that divides the discriminant, which is something like $-(B-A)(2A+B)^2.$ Anything short of that (as the few rules I gave) will sometimes give the wrong answer. The related thing that might be familiar is the Legendre theorem on integer solutions for $Ax^2 + B y^2 + C z^2$ where $A,B,C$ are nonzero and do not all have the same $\pm$ sign. quick ref: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-251/S0025-5718-05-01729-1/S0025-5718-05-01729-1.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy: Right now, I'm only using three constraints: first, that $\text{GCD}(A,B)=1$, second, that $A$ is not divisible by 4, and third, that $A+B$ is not divisible by 4. Setting $N=1000$, this reduces the number of pairs to consider from approximately 500,000 to 200,000. You also mentioned there are restrictions mod 3... what are they?

Comment: Dumpster, I never worked them out. Maybe a little later. However, a related test is that, if either $B-A$ or $2A+B$ is divisible by some $q^{2k-1}$ but not by $q^{2k},$ with integer $k \geq 1$ and prime $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6,$ then this $(A,B)$ pair is also ruled out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21135/discussion-between-dumpsterdoofus-and-will-jagy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADDED: Another way of saying this: Given integers $B > A > 0,$ with $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ then there is a solution in integers $x,y,z,$ not all $0,$ to
$$  A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - B (yz + zx + xy) = 0, $$
**if and only if both** $B+2A$ **and** $B-A$ are integrally represented by the binary form $u^2 + 3 v^2.$

Well, as i indicated, we can multiply the form by $12$ and diagonalize that over the integers. That will not always be the best way to proceed, but gives an immediate answer in one case the computer program suggested.

Given integers $B > A > 0,$ with $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ let
$$  g(x,y,z) = A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ) - B(yz+zx+xy).  $$
Before continuing, let me point out that the discriminant of $g$ is
$$ \Delta = -(B-A) (2A+B)^2,  $$ and that primes that can be used to rule out solutions of $g=0$ are required to divide $\Delta.$ Furthermore, as the form is indefinite, the number of primes for which we can make such an argument is even: for $A=3,B=14$ we had $ \Delta = -11 \cdot 20^2,$ and the primes that can be used to prove that one impossible are $5,11.$

Then, defining
$$ u = -x-y+2z, \; \; \; v = -x+y, \; \; \; w = x+y+z,  $$ we get diagonalization
$$  12 g = (2A+B) u^2 + 3 (2A+B) v^2 -4(B-A) w^2.  $$

Now, suppose $B$ is divisible by $4.$ We can prove, quickly, that it is impossible to have the above $12g = 0$ in integers, so we cannot have $g=0$ either. IF $B=4 \beta,$ we know that $A$ is odd to have them coprime. So,
$$ 12g = (2A+4 \beta) u^2 + 3 (2A + 4 \beta)v^2 - 4 (4 \beta - A) w^2  $$
is to be set to zero. However, all coefficients are currently even, so we immediately switch to
$$ 6g = (A+2 \beta) u^2 + 3 (A + 2 \beta)v^2 - 2 (4 \beta - A) w^2.  $$
Now, both $A+2\beta$ and $4 \beta - A$ are odd. Using properties of $p^2 + 3 q^2,$ we find that the quantity we abbreviate as $6g$ cannot be divisible by $8$ unless all three of $u,v,w$ are even. Therefore there is no solution in coprime integers to $6g=0,$ and by infinite descent, there is no solution in integers. There is a lemma here, if there is any integer solution, we can divide through by the gcd of the variables, and arrive at a solution with gcd $1.$ But that does not happen; so there cannot be a solution in integers to $g(x,y,z) = 0.$ There is a phrase for this: $g(x,y,z)$ is anisotropic in the $2$-adic numbers $\bf Q_2.$

So, $B$ can't be divisible by $4.$

Same argument if $A+B$ is divisible by $4.$ From $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ this means both are odd. Then, with $B > A > 0,$ we find $B-a \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$ So, with 
$$  12 g = (2A+B) u^2 + 3 (2A+B) v^2 -4(B-A) w^2,  $$
we also get $2A+B$ odd. Let us write $$ 2A + B=\psi , \; \; \; B_A = 2 \omega $$
with $\psi, \omega$ odd. We have
$$  12 g = \psi( u^2 +  3v^2) - 8 \omega \, w^2.  $$
This is not divisible by $16$ unless all three $u,v,w$ are even. So this is again anisotropic in $\bf Q_2.$

So, we cannot have $A+B$ divisible by $4.$

Next, $2A+B$ and $B-A$ cannot both be divisible by $2$ to an odd power if the original form is isotropic. If $B$ is odd, then $2A+B$ is odd, and if $\nu_2 (B-A)$ is odd, the the original for is anisotropic in $\bf Q_2.$ Here $\nu_2$ is the $2$-adic valuation, if we say $\nu_2 n = k$ it means $2^k | n$ but NOT $2^{k+1} | n.$ Next, if $B$ is even we know that $B \neq 0 \pmod 4$ if the thing is isotropic, so actually $B \equiv 2 \pmod 4,$ and then $A$ is odd. But then $B-A$ is odd, so $\nu_2 4(B-A) = 2$ is even. If the original form is isotropic, we must have  $\nu_2 (2A+B)$ even as well.

% Feb. 6
From $\gcd(A,B) = 1.$  Then, with $B > A > 0.$
$$  12 g = (2A+B) u^2 + 3 (2A+B) v^2 -4(B-A) w^2.  $$
Note that 
$$  \gcd(2A+B, 3(2A+B), -4(B-A)  ) \in \{1,2,3,4,6,12 \}.  $$
In particular, we can say something pretty strong when either is divisible by some prime
$$  q \geq 5, \; \; \;  q \equiv 2 \pmod 3.  $$

Theorem 1: if $2A+B$ is divisible by such a prime $q$ but not by $q^2,$ then there is no solution in integers to our $12g = 0,$ because the form is anisotropic in $\bf Q_q.$

Theorem 2:  if $B-A$ is divisible by such a prime $q$ but not by $q^2,$ then there is no solution in integers to our $12g = 0,$ because the form is anisotropic in $\bf Q_q.$

Proofs: if $$  u^2 + 3 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q, $$ then actually
 $$  u,v \equiv 0 \pmod q, $$
$$  u^2 + 3 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {q^2}. $$

So, for example, this immediately takes care of $A=3, B=14$ because $B-A = 11$ and $2B+A = 4 \cdot 5.$

The same conclusions hold if either quantity named is divisible by $q^{2n-1}$ but not by $q^{2n}.$

The primes in question are
$$ 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 71, 83, 89, 101, 107, \ldots  $$
If either $2A+B$ or $B-A$ is divisible by one of these primes, but not its square, we know there cannot be a way to write zero in integers for that pair $(A,B).$ I am running a program showing $(A,B)$ pairs that fail, then showing the other two numbers, $2A+B$ and $B-A$ and how each factors. In most cases of failure one can easily find one or two of these primes present.

% Feb. 14

It is simpler than I had feared. We take $0 < A < B,$ and $\gcd(A,B)=1.$ After that, what we are really concerned about are the two numbers that come up in diagonalizing the form, those being $B + 2A$ and $B-A.$

The form is isotropic over the rationals (and integers) if and only if:

(I) when factoring both $B + 2A$ and $B-A,$ the exponents of $2$ are even.

(II) when factoring both $B + 2A$ and $B-A,$ the exponents of $q$ are even, where $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6$ is a prime.

That's it. Note that we could combine these into one test, for all primes $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$

Another way of saying this: Given integers $B > A > 0,$ with $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ then there is a solution in integers $x,y,z,$ not all $0,$ to
$$  A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - B (yz + zx + xy) = 0, $$
if and only if both $B+2A$ and $B-A$ are integrally represented by the binary form $u^2 + 3 v^2.$

% Feb. 16 2015

Turned out finding $x,y,z$ can be made mechanical as well, once $2A+B$ and $B-A$ are represented by $u^2 + 3 v^2.$ Notice that I actually use $4(B-A)$ instead!

Given
$$ p^2 + 3 q^2 = 2 A + B,  $$
$$ r^2 + 3 s^2 = 4(B-A),  $$
we can solve 
$$ A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = B (yz + zx + xy)  $$
with
$$ x =  2  p^2  + 6  q^2   -  p  r - 3  p  s + 3  q  r - 3  q  s,  $$
$$ y =  2  p^2  + 6  q^2   -  p  r + 3  p  s - 3  q  r - 3  q  s,  $$
$$ z =  2  p^2  + 6  q^2   + 2  p  r  + 6  q  s.  $$

I took $g = \gcd(x,y,z)$ and printed $x/g,y/g,z/g,$ it changes nothing.

```
A    B     2A+B 4(B-A)      p    q    r    s         x    y    z 
1    2        4    4        2    0    2    0         1    1    4  18=18
     2:  1

2    3        7    4        2    1    2    0         8    2   11  378=378
     3:  1

A    B     2A+B 4(B-A)      p    q    r    s         x    y    z 
     4:  0

1    5        7   16        2    1    4    0         3   -1    5  35=35
2    5        9   12        3    0    3    1         0    1    2  10=10
4    5       13    4        1    2    2    0         6    2    5  260=260
     5:  3

5    6       16    4        4    0    2    0         1    1    2  30=30
     6:  1

3    7       13   16        1    2    4    0        23   -1   17  2457=2457
6    7       19    4        4    1    2    0         6    4    9  798=798
     7:  2
```

% Feb. 18, 2015

Given integers $B > A > 0,$ with $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ let
$$  g(x,y,z) = A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ) - B(yz+zx+xy).  $$

Then, defining
$$ r = x+y+z, \; \; \; s = x-y, \; \; \; t = y-z,  $$ we get almost diagonalization
$$  3 g = (A-B) r^2 +  (2A+B) (s^2 + st + t^2 ) .  $$
For me, this makes the prime $2$ easier to see, in that $s^2 + st + t^2$ is even if and only if both $s,t$ are even, in which case the $s^2 + st + t^2$ is divisible by $4.$ Can we have $g$ isotropic in $\bf Z$ and $B$ divisible by $4?$ No, because $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ so $A$ is odd, so $2A+B \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ while $A-B$ is odd, so the thing is anisotropic in $\bf Q_2:$ we would need $r$ even, but then $s^2+st+t^2$ must be even and so $s,t$ are even as well.  Can we have $g$ isotropic in $\bf Z$ and $A+B$ divisible by $4?$ No, because $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ so both $A,B$ are odd, so $A-B \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ while $2A+B$ is odd, so the thing is anisotropic in $\bf Q_2:$ we would need $s^2+st+t^2$  even  so $s,t$ are even, but then $r^2$ is even and $r$ is even as well.  Can we have $g$ isotropic and both $\nu_2 \, (A-B)$ odd and $\nu_2 \, (2A+B)$ odd? No, this means $B$ even, but then $A$ is odd, and $(A-B)$ is odd.

In brief, in order to have  $g$ isotropic in $\bf Z,$ we need  both $\nu_2 \, (A-B)$  and $\nu_2 \, (2A+B)$ even.

Put this with the same observation about primes $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6,$ and it follows that if  $g$ isotropic in $\bf Z,$ then both $ |A-B|$  and $ (2A+B)$ are represented by $s^2 + st + t^2$ or, indeed, $u^2 + 3 v^2.$

The way this worked out, I do not think a student needs to know much of anything about quadratic forms in more than two variables, if these lemmas about binary quadratic forms can be accepted without proof; the first one is easy and breifly discussed above. I think I will revert to letters $x,y.$ I'm afraid the proof of Lemma 2 uses one case of quadratic reciprocity, not much to be done about that. Lemma 4 uses a variety of ingredients; the hardest case is primes that are $1 \pmod 3,$ after that it is just mathematical induction on the number of prime factors dividing the number I'm calling $n.$

Define $\nu_p \, n$ to be the highest exponent of the prime $p$ that gives a divisor of $n.$ That is,  $\nu_p \, n = k$ means
$p^k | n$ but NOT $p^{k+1} | n.$

Lemma 1: if $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is even, then both $x,y$ are even and $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is divisble by $4.$ Therefore we can divide both $x,y$ by $2,$ and repeat. The result is,   $\nu_2 \, (x^2 + x y + y^2)$ is even.

Lemma 2: Given a prime $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6:$ if $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is divisible by $q,$ then both $x,y$ are divisible by $q,$ and $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is divisble by $q^2.$ Therefore we can divide both $x,y$ by $q,$ and repeat. The result is,   $\nu_q \, (x^2 + x y + y^2)$ is even.

Lemma 3: $x^2 + xy + y^2$ and $x^2 + 3 y^2$ represent exactly the same numbers

Lemma 4: If we have a positive number $n$ such that, for every prime $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ we have  $\nu_p \, n$ even, then we can find some integers $x,y$ such that $n = x^2 + 3 y^2.$ We can also find other integers such that  $n = x^2 + xy +  y^2,$ but these $x,y$ may sometimes have opposite $\pm$ signs.

Comment: Thank you. In general, this test can be implemented in Mathematica by `f[{a_, b_}] := 
 FindInstance[b - a == u^2 + 3 v^2, {u, v}, Integers] =!= {} && 
  FindInstance[b + 2 a == u^2 + 3 v^2, {u, v}, Integers] =!= {}`, which is sufficient to replicate your list of $(A,B)$ pairs when used as a filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the issue was previously discussed. It is not clear what meaning to ask the same question?

[Find a solution: $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=10(xy+yz+zx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134075/find-a-solution-3x2y2z2-10xyyzzx/1134935#1134935)

[Solutions to $ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527)

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98932

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98931

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98930

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98929

If these formulas are not satisfied, then we must ask the question more specifically.  What kind of decisions need to look for?

I just can not understand.  A number of different formulas can be written for this equation. Depending on how the coefficients should look, but still stubbornly use the computer to search solutions.

Can this have any meaning? I don't understand! I can explain what is the meaning?

Comment: individ, here is a problem that you might enjoy: it turns out that given integers $B > A > 0$ with $\gcd(A,B)=1,$ then we can solve $A (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = B (yz+zx+xy)$ in integers, not all zero, if and only if BOTH $B+2A$ AND $B-A$ have representations as $u^2 + 3 v^2.$ See my latest answer... Now, Ark very much wants a parametrization of the pairs $(A,B)$ that succeed, if, for example, three variables it would be polynomials $g(i,j,k) = A$ and $h(i,j,k) = B.$ I do not, yet,  know how to find such things.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions to the equation. To get infinite amount of different.

$$A(x^2+y^2+z^2)=B(xy+xz+yz)$$

If you can imagine.    $$A=ps$$  $$B=p^2+s^2$$

Then decisions can be recorded.

$$x=pt^2-(p^2+s^2)tk+s(p^2-ps+s^2)k^2$$

$$y=st^2-(p^2+s^2)tk+p(p^2-ps+s^2)k^2$$

$$z=tk(p-s)^2$$

If you can imagine.  $$A=s(s-2p)$$  $$B=p^2+2s^2$$

Then decisions can be recorded.

$$x=(s-2p)t^2+2(p+s)tk+sk^2$$

$$y=(s-2p)t^2-2(p+s)tk+sk^2$$

$$z=(p+4s)t^2-pk^2$$

$t,k$ - integers which we ask.